# What does => syntax mean in XQuery?

Tags: xml, xquery

Having troubles understanding the "=>" syntax in XML while doing a exam exercise. Searched the web for it but cant find the meaning of it. Here is the example from a exam which the syntax is used in:

```
FOR $b IN //Brand
LET $cars :=
    (FOR $c IN //Car
    LET $cb := $c/@model => //Model/..
    WHERE $cb/@name = $b/@name
    RETURN $c)
LET $nr := COUNT($cars)
RETURN <Brand name={$b/@name}>{$nr}</Brand>
```

It is goal is to count all cars for each brand.

This was my try:

```
FOR $b IN //Brand
LET $cars := (
   FOR $c IN //Car
   WHERE $c/@Model = $b/Model/@name //Might not work to match against all models this way?
   RETURN ({c})
RETURN <Brand name={$b/@name}>COUNT($cars)</Brand>
```

And this is the XML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE CarsNStars [
<!ELEMENT CarsNStars (Brand*, Car*)>
<!ELEMENT Brand (Model*)>
<!ELEMENT Model (Year+)>
<!ELEMENT Year (#EMPTY)>
<!ELEMENT Car (#EMPTY)>
<!ATTLIST Brand
   name ID #REQUIRED
   country CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST Model
   name ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Year
   year CDATA #REQUIRED
   horsePower CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST Car
   regNr ID #REQUIRED
   model IDREF #REQUIRED
   miles CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
```

Edited WHEN to WHERE, this must obviously been a typo from the lecturer.

Comment: $cb should be  returning the specific car's brand, if i understand the query correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `=>` isn't defined in either XQuery spec (1.0 or 3.0). Neither is `WHEN`.

Comment: That scumbag teacher... (;

Any idea what that line can be replaced with for the same result? Would my version of the query work=?

Comment: According to your doctype, its seems so. You are basically joining Brand/Model/@name with Car/@model. I think the doctype is confusing and designed to mimic SQL, which is not usually good practice. Also, XML Schema is typically are more appropriate for XQuery (rather than doctype) because the types line up, and there is more ecosystem support for validation etc.

Comment: Moreover, keywords such as "for" and "let" in XQuery are lower-case.